# How do I create a particle system with an object that already has a particle system

Tags: particles

I am working on a project and used a particle system to create the branches of a tree. I am now trying to make take that tree and create another particle system in order to create a forest with many of these trees. The problem is when I create the second particle system the trees show up without the branches of the tree or the first particle system. Lmk what I can do to solve this problem or if there is any other information you need to answer.

Comment: Generating particles from particles can be a bit tricky because paarticles need an emitter and another particle does not count as an emitter (there is no mesh data to emit from). This video gives a pretty good description of how to do it - The part about the particles from particles starts at 7:08. - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UpvNJvsq-FU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the modifier tab on the source object, apply the particle system modifier. This will turn the branches of the tree into individual objects. Then, select all of the branches as well as the tree trunk as the active object and join them together. This will give you one object that can then be used as the object when rendering the forest particle system.